# Specify DirectoryIndex for all directories but a specific one?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I am serving a collection of Web applications from a Windows machine running Apache.  My document root has the following contents:

```
/MyWebApp1
/MyWebApp2
/MyWebApp3
/Common
  /css
  /images
  /script
```

I want that `index.php` be served whenever the root folder, or a folder corresponding to a Web application is specified:

```
/          ==> /index.php
/MyWebApp1 ==> /MyWebApp1/index.php
/MyWebApp2 ==> /MyWebApp2/index.php
/MyWebApp3 ==> /MyWebApp3/index.php
```

But I don't want to specify a directory index for `/Common` and its subfolders:

```
/Common        ==> Error 403
/Common/css    ==> Error 403
/Common/images ==> Error 403
/Common/script ==> Error 403
```

How can I do that?

---

**EDIT**: By the way, the number of Web applications I am hosting will grow in the future, and I don't want to reconfigure Apache each time I add a Web application. Explicitly enumerating each `MyWebApp<i>` is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
<Location />
     Options +Indexes
<Location>
<Location /Common>
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

You might use this on server level (not inside VirtualHost) if your apps are in different hosts.

See also:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html